# Expand columns with vectors as items

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a dataframe with the following format

```
Position   data     
48575185    1
48575150    3
48604751    5
48604673    c(3,5)
48591918    2
48591919    8
```

Some data in the data column is a numerical and some are vectors of numbers.  I want to create a new dataframe that makes a new copy of the row with each value in the vector for rows with a vector item, essentially expand the table to:

```
Position   data     
48575185    1
48575150    3
48604751    5
48604673    3
48604673    5
48591918    2
48591919    8
```

How do I do this in r? I am very new to R. I found a function called expand(), but am unsure if that is what I need in this situation.

Comment: I don't a data frame can have a vector as an element, and I'm not even sure that a list in general can do this.  Please include your relevant code.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen - code is certainly needed to know what OP is working with, but you can have a `list` column in a `data.frame`, including a `vector` - `data.frame(a=I(list(1,3,5,c(3,5))))`

Comment: Just do `df1 %>% unnest`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using `unnest` from the `tidyr` package. This allows you to convert each element in the list into a separate row. Assuming your data frame is called `df`

```
df %>% unnest(data)
```

Or if you want to unnest all columns

```
df %>% unnest()
```

Answer (score 0):

We could use `gsub` with `tidyr::separate_rows`

```
df %>%
    mutate(data = gsub("(c\\(|\\))", "", data)) %>%
    separate_rows(data)
#  Position data
#1 48575185    1
#2 48575150    3
#3 48604751    5
#4 48604673    3
#5 48604673    5
#6 48591918    2
#7 48591919    8
```

---

### Sample data

```
df <- read.table(text =
    "Position   data
48575185    1
48575150    3
48604751    5
48604673    c(3,5)
48591918    2
48591919    8", header = T)
```

Answer (score 0):

I realize this answer is a bit late to the game, but here's an `data.table` implementation:

```
library(data.table)
dt = data.table(Position = c(48575185, 48575150, 48604751, 48604673, 48591918, 48591919),
                data = list(1,3,5,c(3,5), 2,8) )
dt[,lapply(.SD, unlist),.SDcols = 'data', by = 'Position']
```